# Meteor: How can I publish and subscribe a user avatar from the public folder?

Tags: meteor, avatar

Im creating an instant messenger app and I am wondering how I can access the users avatar from the public folder and username from the collection. I would like the username and avatar to appear next to the users message. I keep getting a broken image and [object Object]. Object Object, should be username with the avatar. [image: Check out this image.]

Template

```
<template name="chat_message">
    <div class = "container">
        <div class = "row">
            <img src="/{{profile.avatar}}" class="avatar_img">
            {{username}} said: {{text}} 
        </div>
    </div>  
    <br>
</template>
```

Client Side

```
Meteor.subscribe("userData");
Meteor.subscribe("users");

Template.chat_message.helpers ({
    username: function() {
      var userId = this.userId;
      var user = Meteor.users.findOne(userId);
      var username = user && user.profile && user.profile.username;
      var avatar = user && user.profile && user.profile.avatar;

      return {
        username: username,
        avatar: avatar
      } 
    },
  });

  Template.chat_page.helpers({
    messages:function(){
      var chat = Chats.findOne({_id:Session.get("chatId")});
      return chat && chat.messages;
    }, 
    other_user:function(){
      return ""
    }, 

  });
```

Server Side

```
Meteor.publish("userData", function(){
  return Meteor.users.find({_id: this.userId});
});

Meteor.publish("users", function(){
    return Meteor.users.find({ "status.online": true })
});

  Meteor.methods({
    sendMessage: function (chat) {
      Chats.insert({
        chat: chat,
        createdAt: new Date(),
        username: Meteor.user().profile.username,
        avatar: Meteor.user().profile.avatar,
      });
    },
  });
```

Comment: Are you using a package for avatar creation/consolidation? If so, which one?

Comment: No, I haven't used any packages. Would it best to use one?

Comment: It's up to you, but there are several issues with your code. Some of them are addressed by the answer (although I would not recommend all of the advice given there). Please share a sample of what a user object looks like, and, in particular, its profile. Think hard on your data - what do you want to store in each chat message and in each chat. For one, if the user name and avatar are stored in the chat message, you don't need the `users` collection in order to get it.

Comment: Thank you, I made some changes. Im not able to pull up the avatar and the username. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved it like this:
You can insert username and avatar in msg array like this...

```
Template.chat_page.events({
 // this event fires when the user sends a message on the chat page
 'submit .js-send-chat':function(event){
   // stop the form from triggering a page reload
   event.preventDefault();
   // see if we can find a chat object in the database
   // to which we'll add the message
   var chat = Chats.findOne({_id:Session.get("chatId")});
   if (chat){// ok - we have a chat to use
     var msgs = chat.messages; // pull the messages property
     if (!msgs){// no messages yet, create a new array
       msgs = [];
     }
     // push adds the message to the end of the array
     var user = Meteor.user().profile.username;
     var avatar = Meteor.user().profile.avatar;
     msgs.push({text: event.target.chat.value, user:user, avatar:avatar});
     // reset the form
     event.target.chat.value = "";
     // put the messages array onto the chat object
     chat.messages = msgs;

     // update the chat object in the database.
     Chats.update(chat._id, chat);
   }
 }
})
```

And the template.....

```
<template name="chat_message">
  <img src="/{{avatar}}" alt="user" class="chat-img" />
  {{user}}:  {{text}}
  <br />
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I used for a similar task:

Server:

```
Meteor.publish("chats", function(){

    return Chats.find({$or:[
                {user1Id:this.userId}, 
                {user2Id:this.userId}
                ]});
  });

Meteor.publish("users", function(){

    return Meteor.users.find();

  });
```

Methods:

```
Meteor.methods({

    addChat:function(otherUserId){
        var currentUser = this.userId;
        var otherUser = otherUserId;
        var id = Chats.insert({user1Id:currentUser, user2Id:otherUser});
        return id;
    }, //end of method for adding chat items    


    addMessage:function(chat){
        Chats.update(chat._id, chat);
    },//end of method for adding a message

});
```

Helpers:

```
  Template.chat_page.helpers({
    messages:function(){
      var chat = Chats.findOne({_id:Session.get("chatId")});
      return chat.messages;
    }, 
    other_user:function(){
      return ""
    }, 

  })


  Template.chat_message.helpers({
    user:function(){
    var currentId = Session.get('chatId');
    console.log(Chats.findOne({_id:Session.get("chatId")}));
    console.log(Meteor.user()._id);
    return Meteor.user()._id;
      },
  });
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried it but it didn't work. Should I make changes on the method too?

Comment: I am editing the answer, just try to copy the way I implemented this.